# RSK on matrices with non-integer values

Tags: co.combinatorics, robinson-schensted-knuth

In the usual RSK algorithm, matrices with non-negative integer valued entries are mapped bijectively to a pair of tableaux. The length of the top row of either of the tableaux gives the maximal weight of an up-right path from the $(1,1)$ entry of the matrix to the $(n,n)$ entry. The weight of an up-right path is the sum of the entries of the matrix it encounters.

Is there a generalization of RSK that works with real-valued matrices with non-negative entries that has this same property? I don't really care if it's a bijection anymore.

Comment: You can certainly define the same map acting on non-integer-valued matrices; see http://mit.edu/~shopkins/docs/rsk.pdf for details. This might be called "piecewise-linear" RSK. By "detropicalizing" this map you get "birational" RSK, where maximums become sums and sums become products. Birational RSK goes back at least to Kirillov but has subsequently been much-studied of late (especially with connections to probability).